# Google Maps not loading when my page is accessed over https

Tags: laravel, google-maps-api-3, https

I am trying to include a map from Google Maps on my website. However, Google Maps won't load when my page is accessed over https, but it does work perfectly when my page is accessed over plain http. I'm using Laravel and don't have much experience with this framework yet.

[this](http://enhance.lk/public/listings/dinza-car-audiobody-styling-spare-parts-car-modification-negombo/4) is the http-link and [this](https://enhance.lk/public/listings/dinza-car-audiobody-styling-spare-parts-car-modification-negombo/4) is the https-link.

Answer (score 2):

When you navigate to your website via the https url, the Google map doesn't show up because it fails to load its script via

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js ..."></script>
```

This is because your website is loaded over **https** and the script over **http**, which is known as the **mixed-content problem**.

You solve this by also loading the Google maps script over https

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js ..."></script>
```

Comment: Hi can you please tell me from where i can edit this m and thank your for your response

Comment: I noticed the `script` tag above on line 422 when doing a view-source (html) on the page/url in your question. Easiest way to find out where this script is coming from is by doing a search over your code files. I can't see these from here.

Comment: done thank you for the help, is there any way i can give you points or something